# JavaScript for Resolution detection,but seems returning wrong

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

i'm trying to create a simple JS on a simple HTML,what i'm trying to do is when the `window.screen.availWidth` returning a specific value it will replace itself with specified HTML page on other directory.But my problem is it look like that the value always returned to 1920 because i've tried in on a 1366 pixel width screen and it always show page for 1920 pixel width screen.Anyone can help ?
Full Code

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript1.2">

var width = window.screen.availWidth;

if (width = 1920)
    {
   window.location.replace('Judul/Judul_1920.html');
    }
else if (width = 1366)
    {
window.location.replace('Judul/Judul_1366.html');
    }
else if (width = 1360)
    {
window.location.replace('Judul/Judul_1366.html');
    }
else if (width = 1024)
    {
window.location.replace('Judul/Judul_1024.html');
    }
else
    {
window.location.replace('Judul/Judul_Legacy.html')
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or maybe somebody could suggest a more efficient way ? Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width = 1920` is an assignment, `width == 1920` is a comparisson. Use

```
if (width == 1920) {

}
```

instead.

And maybe you're better of with `width >= 1920` for the case someone has an odd resolution.

Comment: Thankyou,And it works like a charm.by the way what is the diffrence between assigment and comparison ?

Comment: @TommyAriaPradana Assignment is "make the variable this value", comparison checks if the expression is equal to the value.